# Can you give example of some problems with solutions in each of Newtonian, Lagrangian and Hamiltonian method?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism, big-list

I am a student from information system and just want to know about classical mechanics. I know Newtonian mechanics from high school and I have read about Lagrangian and Hamiltonian mechanics in intuitive manner. Can you use an example to outline the basic characteristics (and key differences) of Newtonian, Lagrangian and Hamiltonian methods in their approach to classical mechanics problems?

Comment: The proper state of this question is under [discussion on meta](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5758/is-this-question-too-broad-and-if-so-can-it-be-fixed).

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/8903/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/44722/2451 and links therein.

Comment: thats exactly that i need, 
http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5758/is-this-question-too-broad-and-if-so-can-it-be-fixed 
comment from @dmckee 
Thanks all

Comment: Please do not edit answers into questions. That is not in keeping with the model we use here.