# Lagrangian mechanics

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism

I'm new in this area, and I have some trouble understanding the next concepts, I'll be glad if somebody can give a sample definition or some examples of the concept of "Local Lagrangian" and "configuration variables" on sistems with finite-number or freedom degrees. Thanks in advice.

Comment: Local Lagrangian part has  duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/95018/

Comment: It's right to say "Local Lagrangian" are the same that "Local Lagrangian Density"?

Comment: Almost always AFAIK, density is implied.

Comment: Configuration space is explained here: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/185612/2451