# What is the added value of the lagrangian?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism

In the case of classical mechanics, when describing the movement of a particle that is subject to a force, Newton's law gives us the law of motion of the particle:
$$F(t)=m\cdot a(t)$$

We can also apply the Lagrangian instead:
$$L=\frac 1 2 m\cdot v^2 - V(x)$$
Applying the principle of least action by the Euler-Lagrange equation we get:
$$\frac d {dt}\frac {dL}{dv}=\frac {dL}{dx}$$
Which simply reduces to Newton's equation.

**My question is**: If minimizing the action simply reduces to finding Newton's equation, then what is the added value of the lagrangian in the first place? Why not just start with Newton's equations?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/254266/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/15899/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/8903/2451 and links therein.

Comment: As you solve more and more complicated mechanics questions, the utility of the lagrangian approach will be become evident! :)