# Automatically embedded in Lagrangian formulation

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, constrained-dynamics

Since bond forces are automatically embedded in Lagrangian formulation, while in Newton they are not, and you have to operate directly with them [you have freedom from generalized coordinates]. That's true? Is there a disadvantage of Lagrangian compared to Newtonian formulation?

Comment: By bond forces do you mean constraint forces?

Comment: @Qmechanic yes,,,

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/8903/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/254266/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/292710/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Lagrangian formalism is advantageous because we don't want to mess with each force separately using Newton's laws. The automatic constraints are, in fact, the advantage of the Lagrangian formalism over Newton's laws.