# What is the essence of Lagrangian/Hamiltonian mechanics?

Tags: hamiltonian-formalism, history, hamiltonian

I'm reading on the calculus of variations, and Hamiltonian mechanics is discussed there. However, I'm not a physicist, so I cannot very well place the concept of Hamiltonian Mechanics in perspective.

Wikipedia treats Hamiltonian Mechanics in a very formal way.

**That's why I hope someone can explain to me what is the *essential insight*, or the *essential change in approach*, of Hamiltonian Mechanics.**

I'd like to understand conceptually-historically what the change in mathematical approach is compared to Newtonian mechanics, what the change in intuition is, the insight that precipitates it, and why it is significant.

**Edit**: This question is different from [this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/44722), in that I'm asking more for the conceptual (and historical) significance and change of perspective of Hamiltonian Mechanics, rather than what I need to do to learn it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What exactly are Hamiltonian Mechanics (and Lagrangian mechanics)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/44722/)

Comment: For physicists, the primary function of Hamiltonian Mechanics was to set the stage for the transition from classical (Newtonian) mechanics to Quantum Mechanics.